# Having the image at the third second of a video

Tags: c#, video, bitmap

I'm desperately trying to recover the image to the third second of a video, in MP4 format as Bitmap.

I need this to analyze the image and get some information from it.

I've tried a lot of things but nothing works or it doesn't work so please don't send me a link to another post.

Thank you for the person who will take the time to answer me and guide me.

Comment: There may not be an image at this timestamp. If there is an I-Frame you are lucky. But if not, you need to decode your way to that timestamp from the last I-Frame. But still, you may not hit that _exact_ timestamp.

Comment: _"I've tried a lot of things"_ Show the command you tried and we'll help you fix it. Use the [**edit** option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63153260/edit) to add your attempt code. Also try just exporting as images (since only 3 seconds) and use the `expectedNum.png` for your analysis.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I don't have the exact 3rd second, the part I can get back and between the 1st second and the 5th.

Comment: That _"exact second"_ problem could be the keyframe issue mentioned above by @Fildor. I'll test a possible solution for you soon. PS: You're likely getting downvoted for not showing a code attempt (in case you want to get it canceled).

Comment: ah, okay. I'll try to put one on if I have time.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/cmxl/FFmpeg.NET#grab-thumbnail-from-a-video)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the first example from [the docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking):

```
ffmpeg -i timecode.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -frames:v 1 out_second_3.png
```

I tested it with [this timecode video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYquWP-NHM) and got the result below (share your video file if possible) :

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not C#... x) I've got a foreach loop with the file names How can I use it?

Comment: @Zone2Risk Put up your code, we'll have a look into it.

Comment: `foreach(string file in filePaths)
                {

                }` I don't know how that helps.

Comment: @Zone2Risk a `For Each` loopis not enough. You need a decoder (that converts the video's compression into an actual picture). What are you using? You must show enough code in [your main post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63153260/edit) to recreate your problem. A small demo app that loads a video and tries to extract. then we can test it ourselves and possibly help you fix that

Comment: @Zone2Risk my answer is using FFmpeg.exe. It's a free command line media tool that can be also run via C# (as an external `Process`). Download it [**here**](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) after choosing 32-bit or 64-bit. Practice in the commandline for a short while then later tell C#' to do it automatically...